# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in GOOGLE MAPS API V3

Tags: javascript, maps

I'm trying to load polygon path in Google Maps V3, and everything works if encoded line is short. But if it's longer like this - I get error above. I think its somehow related to '@' character. Action is in Chrome!!

```
polyShape.setPath(google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath("snfiIwfxtCXhGfEbLzAhJRbPYlPk@jHmCxJMlE?hJeBtE}Ed_@_AxN{AbLkCrGcHlTsDrKoBpNRzH?vE?jHl@pGtA~IfCfFvHpCLnBm@~FqH~[aCzRs@rZg@dI{Hx]qLze@_L|SmHpJyMfFyDoBcHiGuCwBcHtAkAs@MoFiBoF}BViBvEmGvF_ElIuAjDwJvEiB`DB|AhB|DxAnFXhGSpG_GdIgLi@gHbAsB|DWhGeB~F}FzAgAjAwEfMkH|AuBdB{@hCwBzIaBrDIzBR~BPdArCrJd@dE@rKe@vIy@`HK`NKqBrOmBfEsBvK...."));
```

Comment: Since the path could be the problem, I'd suggest you post it in full.

Comment: Okay. Full path:

}w}hImh|sCb@e@~@kBvE}CxClGbDbFxEpLfF`XbEvDtBmA|BpAvDo@hDqDb@_JjB~Do@rGqC`F}P~GcAuBwBb@iEcBmDkAkKiFQoH{AoN{Cc@i@sCi@wBbAyEU}D